When using the GAS in UE5, in addition to character attributes, can the parameters of projectiles and weapons also be put into the attributeset?
My game needs a very flexible Buff system, Buffs can modify the character's attributes but also the parameters of projectiles, weapons, and even other buffs, so are all these parameters defined in AttributeSet?
For example, I have the following effect: 'Ice Spike' - Surrounds the protagonist and flies towards the enemy when it finds them, dealing 30 points of damage, with up to 2 present at the same time. Applies a layer of 'cold' to the target on hit.
BuffA: Ice Spikes damage is increased by 50% and the cap is increased to 3.
